# Get the value of obserable inside obserable rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have below Observable

```
  config$: Observable<QueryBuilderConfig>;

this.config$.pipe(map(item => {
  return {
    fieldGroups: [
      { id: CustomAttributeEntityType.Risk, label: this.l('Risk') },
      { id: CustomAttributeEntityType.RiskAssessment, label: this.l('Risk Assessment') }
    ],
    fields: this.metricCreateConfigureStore.queryBuilderFields$, // Get the value from obserable
    allowEmptyRules: true,
    allowEmptyRulesets: false
  }
}));
```

In the `field` attribute, I want to get the value from another observable, something like below

```
 fields: this.metricCreateConfigureStore.queryBuilderFields$
```

`queryBuilderFields$` return `Observable` as below

```
readonly queryBuilderFields$: Observable<{ [key: string]: QueryBuilderFieldsDto }> = this.select(state => state.queryBuilderFields);
```

How can I get the value, without subscribe over there??

Comment: Hello, if the initial condition for this to work is the `queryBuilderFields$`, you should use it first in your stream, and use `switchMap` operator to continue with the `config$` Observable. You can find details of the mechanism here : https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/.

Comment: @AlainBoudard can you please show an example on my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you exactly mean by "value from other observable": two streams emitting independently, and you want to catch values from both? That's

```
combineLatest([stream1$, stream2$])
    .subscribe(([val1$, val2$]) => //...
```

Or use value from one stream to create another one? That's `switchMap` (or maybe one of its siblings, like `concatMap`, `mergeMap` etc.):

```
stream1$.pipe(
    tap(/* maybe some side effects here */),
    switchMap(value1 => generateStream2(value1))
).subscribe(value2 => //...
```

Comment: There, that exactly @mbojko :)

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like

```js
this.metricCreateConfigureStore.queryBuilderFields$.pipe(
   switchMap((fields) => this.config$.pipe(
      map((item) => {
         return { ... use fields and item }
      })
   ))
)
```

And also, I would not use `this.l()` function call inside the stream handlind, but put a parameter to be used, so pure function.